# How to send JUNIT fail when a testcase is failing?

Tags: selenium, junit

I have a scenario like i want to make my JUNIT fail when one of my test case is failing.

I am running keywords/testcases under one @Test annotation using a JNUIT framework. When one test case is failing, the JUNIT is not showing any FAIL as i am handling everything under try catch block. But every keyword is returning a status either fail or pass when it is completed. So i want to send junit fail when the status is failing.

Is there any way to send failures to JUNIT?

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Would you share a piece of code with your problem?

Comment: added the piece of code and i want to fail the JUNIT as per the variable testStatus

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**fail()**](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#fail%28java.lang.String%29) method to explicitly fail a test

```
try{
  // do stuff...
  fail("No exception");
}catch(Exception e){
  //...      
}
```